# Kill a procedure triggered by an event automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, mysql-5.7

There is a procedure called "daily_feed" as follows:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`micro_bi`@`%` PROCEDURE `microservices_bi`.`DAILY_FEED`()
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS abc;
CREATE TABLE abc AS
SELECT a,b,c
FROM my_table1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS efg;
CREATE TABLE efg AS
SELECT e,f,g
FROM my_table2;
END
```

There is an event also called "DAILY_FEED" to execute the above procedure on a daily-basis as follows:

```
CREATE EVENT daily_feed
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR
STARTS '2022-01-27 03:30:00.000'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO CALL DAILY_FEED()
```

The procedure gets executed every morning at 03:30 and it takes 6 hours to be completed.

The issue is that if I want to kill the process in the middle, I can't because nothing would pop up in

```
SHOW processlist;
```

Therefore, I can't see the relevant id from processlist, and I can't KILL the process.

I need to kill the procedure, how is it possible? The server is located on AWS and I can't restart it myself.

Comment: You can kill the event with `DROP EVENT daily_feed` .

Comment: @Riz In a test I am doing, dropping or disabling the event does not interrupt the current execution.

Comment: Does your use at least have PROCESS privilege? You should be able to see processes run by the event scheduler. I am testing this but I am testing with MySQL 8.0 on my laptop, not RDS.

Comment: `This statement requires the EVENT privilege for the schema to which the event to be dropped belongs.` You are lacking event privilges then. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_event

Comment: Thanks guys for your time. Dropping the event didn't work, I tried it yesterday night. Also, I have the procedure privilege to create, alter, and drop any procedure. But, I can't see if a procedure stuck or not. Thanks again

Comment: @miladbaharijavan, do you even see the event with sow events? Also, have you checked the general/error logs of RDS?

Comment: @Riz Yeah I can see all events. Unfortunately I do not have access to the logs.